# How to optimize the clique problem when permuting a known graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Say I have a complete undirected graph with a fixed number of nodes where each edge is one of a fixed number of colors. I have a program that runs which

1) alters the graph by changing the color of one of the edges
2) recalculates maximal cliques for each affected color (using Bron Kerbosch)
3) produce output, repeat from 1)

This process can be rather computationally expensive. I'm wondering if this can be optimized by some amount of pre-processing as only one edge is changing at a time.

For example, I'm thinking I can store a list of cliques which exist. When an edge changes, I can seed the Bron Kerbosch algorithm with one of the changed nodes instead of evaluating the color graph again. And then update my list of cliques accordingly. (Of course, the first step would be to remove any existing cliques from my list which contain either node). So this would tell me what the maximal cliques are without re-evaluating the entire color graph.

question: When repeatedly modifying an existing graph, is there a more efficient algorithm for finding maximal cliques than naive Bron Kerbosch implmentation?

Comment: If you're doing this process many times, doesn't it make sense to just find all the cliques at the beginning? When you change the color of one single edge, the only reduction in any of the cliques you do is in the one that the edge is contained in. Then you just need to see if that edge can be added to any other cliques, which is pretty easy.

Comment: @Bob1123 adding a new edge to a color graph could result in new cliques being formed, so I'd have to search neighbors in the color graph. And adding a new edge to an existing clique may or may not form a new clique, so I'd need to use something like Bron Kerbosch to answer that. That sounds about the same as outlined in my question.